# Foreach loop nested 3 times troubles

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to the following

Loop for EACH Roof Measurement (`fastbid_inspection_measurement_roof`) row

Then Foreach row grab roof_pitch then do a foreach loop query against

`fastbid_labor_tearoff` where `pitch` is identical to `$Pitch['roof_pitch']`

then taking the result of that row match in `fastbid_labor_tearoff` and calculate its cost.

RIGHT NOW

If there is ONE record it works perfect, however if there is TWO records within `fastbid_inspection_meaasurement_roof` then it will echo TWO results. I would like it to echo a SUM TOTAL of both or ALL records.

Where am I going wrong?

fastbid_inspection_measurement_roof scheme

```
-------------------------------
| id | roof deck | roof_pitch |
-------------------------------
| 01 |    1359   |      5     |
-------------------------------
| 02 |    1211   |      6     |
-------------------------------
```

fastbid_labor_tearoff scheme

```
---------------------------------------------
| id | labor_cost | ground_drop |   pitch  | 
---------------------------------------------
| 01 |    22.50   |      7       |    5    |
---------------------------------------------
| 02 |    23.50   |      7       |    6    |
---------------------------------------------
```

Here is my Foreach Loops

```
$RoofDecksssss = "SELECT * FROM fastbid_inspection_measurement_roof WHERE Prospect_API = '".$prosapi."'";           
foreach ($pdo->query($RoofDecksssss) as $RoofDeck) { 
                 foreach ($RoofPitch as $Pitch) { 
                    $TearOff_Labor_PerPitch = "SELECT * FROM fastbid_labor_tearoff WHERE pitch = '".$Pitch['roof_pitch']."'";
                        foreach ($pdo->query($TearOff_Labor_PerPitch) as $TearOffCost) {
                            $LaborCost = $TearOffCost['labor_cost'];
                            $RoofDeckSQFT = $RoofDeck['roof_deck'];
                            $GroundDropCost = $TearOffCost['ground_drop'] * DeckSqFT_toRawSquare($RoofDeckSQFT);
                            $Total_Labor += $LaborCost *  DeckSqFT_toRawSquare($RoofDeckSQFT);

                            $TotalLaborTearOffCost = $GroundDropCost + $Total_Labor;

                            echo $TotalLaborTearOffCost;
                        }

                } 

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to move this code outside the loop it's current in if you want it to sum properly.

```
echo $TotalLaborTearOffCost;
```

The way you currently have it now, you will get 1 output for each iteration of your loop.

Comment: That is correct, I backed one out and it works. Now I get an error "PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'roof_pitch'"